# why view. getWidth() works in view. post() even if we called in activity'onCreate

Tags: android, android-view

I learned this trick on Android 50 hacks ,but I don't know why this method works .Does anybody have a clue ,I was really confused.

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
    setContentView(R.id.content);
    final View view = findViewById(R.id.need_width_height);
    view.post(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            Log.d(TAG,view.getWidth()+"," + view.getHeight());
        }  
    })
```

Comment: I don't think your question is clear. Can you post some example code?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

> Causes the Runnable to be added to the message queue. **The runnable
>   will be run on the user interface thread.**

This means whatever you place in the `run()` method of the `Runnable` does not run immediately. And when you say it works I assume you mean it returns valid values for the View's height and width which if it's the case, may be more fortuitous than anything else. Your technique relies on the `Runnable` being executed after the View has been assigned its size but there is no guarantee that this will occur (as far as I can see in the documentation.)

If its View width and size you require then use the [onSizeChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method.

Comment: I've look up the source code of  View. post() .It has invoked RootView.getRunQueue().post() ,this method has add an action to a list which I found will be execute by executeActions(). Then I keep digging ,executeActions() was invoked by performTraversals(). And finally  scheduelTraversals(). This is where I stuck.I've also found a post said that the runnable will be executed after drawing is complete. http://stackoverflow. com/questions/3947145/what-event-is-fired-after-all-views-are-fully-drawn .The Question is why execute after drawing. Sorry for my bad formation, I'm posting on my phone.

Comment: Reference the link you gave in your comment, the reply was from Romain Guy. As Romain is part of the Android graphic SDk team you can take what he says as truth. As to why it executes after drawing, ask yourself what would happen if it executed before drawing. Also you have no control over the order of the message queue (as far as I know).